# Am I able to destructure 2 parts of a json objects string value into 2 variables?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using an API to keep track of soccer scores.

Unfortunately in the response object, there isn't a key for each team's score, the value is only available in a string like this:

```
"ft_score": "1 - 0",
```

It would be very helpful if I could destructure the score into 2 separate variables for each team. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: remove space and split `ft_score` by `-`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I do not understand your comment. The code snippet in the question is *clearly* JSON.

Comment: @BrianDrake - Not by the time they're using destructuring on it it isn't. :-) Note that what's shown is a valid property initializer for a JavaScript object. (It's also valid JSON, if that's inside a string). Unfortunately, newbies get confused and use "JSON" to refer to objects in their code, even though those objects were never encoded as JSON text.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yes, it is a snippet of a object literal, as well as a snippet of JSON. But I am sure most people would assume the latter. And the fact that it is only a snippet should not matter. But this is all missing the point, which I only just understood: this question should not be tagged [json]. None of the comments so far clearly explain this.

Comment: @BrianDrake - Between the tag and the word "json" in the title, I figured the OP would understand, but I take your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly, because strings are not destructurable, and you can't apply *operations* during destructuring (I've often wanted to, but at the same time, it would probably make the code unnecessarily complex). You can destructure arrays, objects, and parameter lists (which are conceptually arrays), but not strings.

If you **know** the string will be in that format, you can use `split(" - ")` to get an array.

```
const { ft_score } = theObject;
const [ team1, team2 ] = ft_score.split(" - ");
```

Or just

```
const [ team1, team2 ] = theObject.ft_score.split(" - ");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick!

Comment: @Bryan - Glad that helped. I added a second option btw. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
var score = '1 - 0';
var arr = score.split(" - ");

var team_1 = arr[0];
var team_2 = arr[1];
```

try something like that.

Comment: The question specifically asks about destructuring, but there's no destructuring in this answer.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder The question demonstrates little understanding. Is it referring specifically to JavaScript destructuring, or just using “destructuring” as a generic term? In any case, this answer gets the job done: it extracts the scores.

Comment: "Am I able to destructure 2 parts of a json objects string value into 2 variables?"

If I have understood man asked for value of JSON object to be stored in 2 variables, and that is what script does.

Comment: @AleksandarJockovic - "[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)" has as specific meaning in JavaScript. (But perhaps the OP doesn't know that, either.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this question has nothing to do with JSON. It is about processing strings like `"1 – 0"`; where those strings come from is irrelevant.

[JavaScript destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) applies to objects and arrays. Actually, strings can be treated as arrays (of characters), so destructuring can be applied to strings too. But not in the sense that you want!

For your purposes, you need to convert the string into an appropriate object or array. The straightforward way of doing that, as stated in the other answers, is to use [String#split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
const [score1, score2] = ft_score.split(' - ');
```

Replace `ft_score` with `apiResponse.ft_score` or whatever is appropriate.